# Script ends immediately

Tags: bash

I'm bash on Ubuntu 12.04. Whenever I try to run `script` to record a session, I see the following:

```
% script
Script started, file is typescript
Script done, file is typescript
```

And the contents of the typescript file are:

```
Script started on Tue 14 Jan 2014 08:53:48 AM EST

Script done on Tue 14 Jan 2014 08:53:48 AM EST
```

As you can see, it ends immediately and doesn't allow me to record any commands. Any idea what the problem is?

My `SHELL` variable is set to `/bin/bash`

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is relevant to the problem, but I was required to modify the PATH in `.cshrc` and `.profile` to the following:

.cshrc:

```
setenv PATH `/bin/showpath /u/cs350/sys161/bin /u/cs350/bin standard`
```

.profile:

```
export PATH; PATH=`/bin/showpath /u/cs350/sys161/bin /u/cs350/bin standard`
```

Comment: Check whether you have the `SHELL` environment variable set and, if so, add the value to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my .bashrc had an `exit` command, so the shell was terminating as soon as it was started. Getting rid of that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`script` starts a new shell and waits for its termination (while logging all input and output).  Obviously the newly started shell terminates at once.  It could be that script is trying to start something fishy as a shell (due to various reasons I cannot find out with so little information) and thus fails, it can also be that it starts the correct shell which immediately decides (again for various reasons) to terminate, probably due to misconfiguration.

As a first step you should try to explicitly give the shell you want to use:

```
script -c /bin/bash
```

Choose the correct shell for your system in case `/bin/bash` isn't appropriate.

If this still fails, try typing `/bin/bash` alone and see if that works.  If it doesn't then something is seriously wrong with your system.  If that subshell starts properly, we will have to find out why it won't when started from `script`.

Comment: what exactly is running /bin/bash supposed to do? at the moment, nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: I guess that means the result looked familiar, e. g. because just a new prompt appeared.  That's good.  It's a prompt given out by the subshell.  Did the other tests fail?  Can you describe what you observed?

Comment: Yes they failed. Running `script -c /bin/bash` had the same result as just `script` as described above. By the way, I added some information in my initial post which may be helpful.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem and it's been solved now. Thank you Alfe for your input!

Comment: You should accept your own answer to mark this as the solution that worked for you.  And you could upvote mine if it helped you in finding your solution without providing it right away.